# correct way to add ckeditor templates and plugins in rails3 (asset pipeline)

Tags: templates, plugins, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ckeditor, asset-pipeline

I cannot figure out how to add additional plugins and Templates to a ckeditor config in rails 3 (asset pipeline).
I tried to put all of them into two folders that i created:

/app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/plugins

app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/templates

...without success.
What is the correct way to add ckeditor templates and plugins in rails3?

I'm on
ruby 1.9.3p362
Rails 3.2.11

----------- UPDATE

Now I create a template (starting from a copy of default.js ckeditor template) in

app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/plugins/templates/templates/template.js

and added in the config.js of CKEDITOR:

```
 config.templates_files = [ '/plugins/templates/templates/template.js' ];
```

But I can't access to template

Comment: Not sure if you have had a look at - http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Templates

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes I read it but i can't find a solution specific for Rails. I installed ckeditor-gem for rails and there's no plugin or template folder, neither a default.js for a template to customize. So, I tried to create a template.js file within the folder structure I mentioned above. Then, in config.js file of ckeditor, I added the template.js via config.templates_files... with no luck. Maybe, do I need to configure some path variable to respect rails asset pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

this is an old question but for what is worth i will give my answer:

I dont think there is a correct way to add the templating to the asset pipeline, since on deployment it will get compresed and your file will be gone.

what I did was i add my template.js to my public folder in rails like this:

public -> templates -> template.js

and on my ck config file I added this line:

```
 config.templates_files = [ '/templates/template.js' ];
```

also if you want to add the images for the templates:

public -> templates -> images

and in your template.js file add this line:

```
imagesPath : '/templates/images/'
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Many thanks Rodrigo! I really appreciate this unexpected reply. Now I'm on Rails 4. As soon as I can, I will try to follow your instructions and will give you some feedback. Thank you!